# Prior Art Request: Patent is based on 3GPP/ETSI standard

Tags: prior-art-request, post-grant, standards, wireless

From reading the claims in [this patent](https://www.google.ca/patents/US9065936) it seems like [Allot](http://www.allot.com/) implemented a TDF (Traffic Detection Function) according to the the 3GPP/ETSI specifications. Following specifications, describing the [Sd reference point](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/129200_129299/129212/12.10.00_60/ts_129212v121000p.pdf) and the [overall architecture](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_ts/123200_123299/123203/12.10.00_60/ts_123203v121000p.pdf) are covering the content of the patent.
Specifically, the different claims on: traffic and application detection, online and offline charging rules, DPI (deep packet inspection) and more are all standard functions described in the standard specification.